# Convert blob to images and save it to local folder - Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I'm able to read blob from the richtext field now need to save it as .jgp/png into my local folder

```
Matcher imgMatcher = Pattern.compile( '<img(.+?)>' ).matcher(con.Photo__c);
String imageURL = imageTag.substringBetween( ' src="', '"' );
String decodedURL = imageURL.unescapeHtml4();
PageReference page = new PageReference( decodedURL );
Blob bodyBlob = page.getContent();


//something like this
File file=new File('c://myimages');
image img=new image(bodyBlob); 
img.fomrat='jpg';
img.title='myphoto';
file.save(img);
```

so it stores as image in my local folder. is this possible using apex(salesforce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i achieved, once saved to salesforce folder from there i downloaded the images, hope it helps someone.

```
    Matcher imgMatcher = Pattern.compile( '<img(.+?)>' ).matcher(con.Photo__c);
    String imageURL = imageTag.substringBetween( ' src="', '"' );
    String decodedURL = imageURL.unescapeHtml4();
    PageReference page = new PageReference( decodedURL );
    Blob bodyBlob = page.getContent();    
    Document doc=new Document();
    doc.Body=bodyBlob;
    doc.FolderId='salesforce folder Id';
    doc.Name=con.name;
    doc.Type='jpg';
    Insert doc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce cannot write to your file system.  You have a few options, you can save to an Attachment record or Document record and download it from there, or you can expose the file through a visualforce page that lets you download the file as an attachment if you dont want to have it stored in salesforce at all. something along the lines of:

```
<apex:page contentType="img/jpg" extensions="xxx">{!image}</apex:page>
```

Comment: thanks, yes salesforce cannot write to file system. i saved them as document to a salesforce folder and downloaded from there.